# using xmlhttprequest to get php content

Tags: javascript

i am trying to use an xmlHttpRequest on an url on the same domain.
the url leads to a php file which parses content from another domain and displays information about it.
i try to get that information using

```
var xmlHttp = null;
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
var s = xmlHttp.responseText;
console.log(s);
```

but I just get an empty string and the following warning:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

I tried to google it, but i don't know much about async functions. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: as i said it didn't work. i get only an empty string

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous request means that the client will wait indefinitely till the server provides the response.

Async request means that the client will submit a request and carry on with other tasks while server makes the response ready.

Async is the recommended way of requesting in modern apps.

The easiest way to implement async requests is to use 'fetch...then' construct.

Here is a simple example of making an asynchronous request using 'fetch':

```
fetch('/web-service-url')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json(); 
    })
    .then(function(jsonData) {
        var keys = Object.keys(jsonData);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(keys));
    });
```